# Generating function of cuts of some graph

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, generating-functions, mathematical-physics

Consider the graph $G$, each edge of which has weight $T$. Also consider some [cut](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)) of $G$. We call the weight of the cut - product of all edges included in the cut. Generating function of cuts of $G$ is sum of weights of all cuts.

My question: what good properties have this generating function? For example, may be this function is expressed through the determinant of some matrix?

Motivation: generating function of cuts has strong connection with Ising model.

Comment: I was puzzled by the name "generating functions" (in the usual sense, these are series whose coefficients have for example a combinatorial meaning, for example $1/(1+x-x^2)=1+x+...+ F_nx^n+...$ is the generating function for Fibonacci sequence). I just had a look at http://lbgi.fr/~sereni/Lectures/GC_Spring09/gc09_2.pdf where they explain generating functions in this context are partition functions. Could you say more about that ?

Comment: Moreover you take for the value of the cut the product of weights, not their sum. Can you say which type of graphs are concerned by this convention ?

Comment: I am sorrry for the confusion: I think , that in English "generating function" and "partition function" are synonyms.

Comment: Motivation of a such definition weight is dictated by the definition of the Ising model

Comment: we consider the Ising model on arbitrary graphs G. But in case if graph G is planar , has many nontrivial formulas for defined by me the formula at the beginning of the question